# Array equivalent of [k in keyof T] in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, we can create a type that has all the same properties of some object `obj`.

```ts
const obj = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 'baz'
};

type Keys = {
    [key in keyof typeof obj]: boolean;
}

const obj2: Keys = {
    // ...
};
```

This will *require* `obj2` have properties `foo` and `bar` each with a boolean value.

Is there a way to do the same with arrays?  I have an enum and I want to make a tuple of all of its values.  In this case we'd use a generic.

```ts
enum Enum {
    foo = 'FOO',
    bar = 'BAR'
}

// doesn't quite work
type ArrayType<T> = [ ...(T[keyof typeof T])[] ];

// type is Enum[] rather than [ 'FOO', 'BAR' ]
const arr = Object.values(Enum) as ArrayType<Enum>;
```

Is there a way to get `[ 'FOO', 'BAR' ]`?

Comment: How do you know that `arr` won't be `['BAR', 'FOO']` ?

Comment: Or, even if *you* know it, how is TypeScript supposed to know this, given that property order in an object isn't part of the type?  (e.g., `{foo: 1, bar: 2}` and `{bar:2, foo: 1}` have the same type)

Comment: I considered that.  I guess I was just hoping.  :D

Comment: I mean, you could do something [awful](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dxjcwc) that generates a union of all possible tuples, but it's awful.  Maybe start with your array and [make an enum-like thing from it](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gIgGIHleYA0MmAQgIIBKmAuvBDKJFANwBQbT0MAomAK4BbVDADebGDABmIEAC54SdAAYahCTABGiBYgToAjDTYBfeo3DR2UAJ4AHAKa8BwtLccgpzoegDWDm08YdwcgviFjMDhBBwg7OGAncOFxSQcADzsQBFgQ6VkRELCXADoZEHY0zOzc+ydtZDc64qEShvYTNiA)?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm not understanding you, all you need is `as Enum[]`:

```js
enum Enum {
  foo = 'FOO',
  bar = 'BAR'
}

const arr = Object.values(Enum) as Enum[];
```